# using calendar as date filter for chart using sql in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

[the output of barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Gtj.jpg)I am trying to build a chart for sales amount grouped by date, using datetimepicker field on the form as the filter. I am using the following code but the chart is not showing up. Please help.

```
SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Date= DATEPART(DAY,Date), SUM (Amount) AS Amount 
FROM Sales 
WHERE Date = '" + Me.calender.Value.ToString() + "'
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, Date) ")

Chart1.DataSource = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)
Chart1.Series.Add("Item")
Chart1.Series("Item").XValueMember = "Date"
Chart1.Series("Item").YValueMembers = "Amount"
```

Comment: Welcome to [so], please specify what you mean _the chart not showing up_, any error?  Meanwhile, you may want to change the `WHERE Date = 'Me.datetimepicker1.Value.ToString()'` to `WHERE Date = '" + Me.datetimepicker1.Value.ToString() + "'"`.  If you could, you may want to check the SQL Parameter to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Date= DATEPART(DAY,Date), SUM (Amount) AS Amount 
 FROM Sales 
 WHERE Date = '" + Me.calender.Value.ToString() + "'GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, Date) ")

Comment: Dear Prisoner thank you. I have made changes as you suggested. The chart shows only for current date but not for other dates. Thank you.

Comment: I have added the bar chart above.

Comment: Prisoner, how do I check SQL parameter to prevent sql injection.

Comment: I believe you can search in here or google for the SQL Parameter.  And if you question is fixed, you can append the result in your question, but not rewrite whole question, which other people may not understand what happened.  Otherwise, if you still have question left, you also can append it in your question.

Comment: Thank you prisoner. Do you think that my issue is still on SQL injection?

Comment: the above filter for chart by date works only for one date. When I change the date in datefield, the error throws up "a chart element with the name 'item' already exists in the seriescollection'. please help. @Prisoner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either update your `series` or `clear and add`, otherwise the series will be duplicated.

```
SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Date= DATEPART(DAY,Date), SUM (Amount) AS Amount 
FROM Sales 
WHERE Date = '" + Me.calender.Value.ToString() + "'
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, Date) ")

Chart1.DataSource = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)
' You need to clear the series before you add
Chart1.Series.Clear
Chart1.Series.Add("Item")
Chart1.Series("Item").XValueMember = "Date"
Chart1.Series("Item").YValueMembers = "Amount"
```

Comment: No need to, just mark the answer which solve your problem.  And contribute your knowledge back to this site is fine.